# How to clear the variable values from Flask route function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web, flask

I have created a tiny app, that asks the user for genre, year preference and query API the relevant websites and gets a list of movie names and present it to the user.. I am using Flask to build it, everything is successfully done..

I am actually using a list variable to store the movie names, rating, poster, etc.. that is collected from the API calls and pass that list to the template for presentation..

The issue is, at first try say the user is given a list of 3 movies, then If the user goes to the homepage and make their selection again with different categories the result is presented for the current selection along with the result for previous selections since the variable's values are not cleared..

I tried to clear it using `del output[:]` placing at different positions but nothing works, please help me out...

PS: The code is Long hence not posting here, it is available in my github repo - https://github.com/avinoth/moviesuggester

the current app with issues is running at http://moviesuggest.therth.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining `result` and `output` as global variables, so they persist between separate calls to the function. There's no reason to do that: define them inside the `index` function itself.